Why is the function Access Based Enumeration not working in PowerShell? (Server 2022, VirtualBox)
I am a complete beginner in PowerShell and I need to enable Access Based Enumeration via PowerShell (assignment for an interview invitation)
I have installed Win Server 2022 in VirtualBox.
PowerShell 5.20
When trying to execute a command Get-SmbShare Install | fl * It gives an error
No MSFT_SMBShare objects found with property "Name" equal to "Install". Verify the value of the property and retry.
While the function Get-SmbShare is running ok
What did I make a mistake about?
I need it to ABE work properly - that is, so that the "User" cannot see the shared folder to which he does not have access.

Get-SmbShare does not have an Install option.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/get-smbshare?view=windowsserver2022-ps

@jdweng: Install is an argument, not an option, which positionally binds to the -Name parameter.

The error message tells you that no share named Install exists. Get-SmbShare without arguments lists all defined shares. You need to find the real name of the share of interest, and then - from an elevated session - run something like the following in order to enable ABE for that share: Get-SmbShare $myShareName | Set-CimInstance -Property @{ FolderEnumerationMode = 0 <# AccessBased #> }

@mklement0 : A value is NOT any argument.  The argument name is NAME and the value is INSTALL.

@jdweng: By argument I mean parameter value. The parameter name is Name in this case, and it is the -Name parameter that the Install string value positionally binds to. (it is a positional argument). Argument and parameter are - unfortunately - sometimes used interchangeably, but in PowerShell the consistently used term for the abstract placeholders to which values are bound on invocation is parameter. Whatever you want to call it, you mistook the value  passed to an abstract placeholder (which you called option in your initial comment) for the name of the latter.
